# Delphi DBgrid change column width

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have problem with column width in dbgrid in delphi. I get result from database and i has three columns `ID`, `Name`, `Description`. 
Name and description has width about `2000+`. I try to change in `DBGrid > Columns > description > width = 300` but not work. Again when i compaile my columns has to much `width`. How to slove this? I want to be ajusted in parent.

[image]

Comment: I've never had this problem, and I routinely deal with DB fields that are very wide (including memo fields containing thousands of characters). How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Does f.ex. `DBGrid.Columns[1].Width := 100;` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to add columns object.

By IDE: right click on DBGrid, columns editor then "Add all fields..."
By runtime: you must create a Column objects.

This is a small example:

```
var vColumn: TColumn;
begin
  vColumn := DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
  // Now you can assign the right properties
  vColumn.Field := yourfield
  vColumn.Width := yourwidth
```

Comment: Loking at the image, it appears that the grid already has the columns. What good does it do to add more columns?

Comment: If you haven't create any TColumn DBGrid show always all columns available in dataset. It's not clear if the change of width is made by IDE or runtime = maybe no Column objects  are created

Answer (score 1):

You have to set **Displaywidth** of the field of Dataset to which DBGrid is pointing to.

[image]